# How to insert node in the middle in C

Tags: c, linked-list

```
NODE* insertNode (NODE* head, NODE* pre, DATA item)
{
//Local Declaration
NODE* curr;

//Statement
if (!(curr = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE)))
    printf("\amemory overflow in insert\n");

curr->data = item;
if (pre == NULL)
{
   //inserting before first node or to empty list
   curr->next = head;
   head = curr;
}
else 
{
   //inserting in middle or at the end
   curr->next = pre->next;
   pre->next = curr;
}

return head;
}
```

this is how I insert node in the middle of an existing list according to the book that I'm reading. But, it doesn't really show me how `pre` is defined here(`pre` is pointing to the predecessor node.) How do I define `pre` pointer so that it points to predecessor node?

Comment: This doesn't have enough context to be a full question.

Comment: I think if `curr` and `next` are in a linked list, then `pre` already points to the now-previous node.

Comment: Can you post the whole code of your linked list?

Comment: only a double-linked list has a `pre`...

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Here's the whole code

Answer (score 2):

[This link](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf) is, IMHO, the master introduction to linked lists.

What the book is illustrating is the "3 step link"...

Suppose {a,b,c} are structs/nodes such that **a** ==> **b** ==> **c** ==> *NULL*

Then to insert **NEW** immediately after **a** you first link: **NEW** ==> **b** *(this first, because if you reset **a**'s pointer first, you will have serious trouble getting to **b**!*

Then link a to **NEW** like... **a** ==> **NEW** ... so we have **a** ==> **NEW** ==> **b** ==> **c** ==> *NULL*

---

To do this, the nodes must have pointers in them... something like:

```
struct node{
  int i;
  struct node* next; // this is the value that will be changed
};
```

As you can see, the precise definition of the node doesn't matter, as long as it contains a pointer to another node.

---

`curr` points to the *current* node... so to get "previous", you could create a *complimentary pointer* to another node, **as I assume** `NODE* pre` is in your question.

But it is unnecessary, really, because just using the `->` operator is much simpler than having several pointers. You can use it to point to other nodes just as well.

So, for my {a,b,c} example, assume `a`, `b` and `c` are all unique `struct node`s, connected as shown before.

```
struct node* curr = a;   // a pointer to the head of the list
struct node NEW = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); // make a new node

NEW->next = curr->next;  // set NEW's next to point to b through `curr->next`
/* note that defining previous isn't necessary, b/c it is defined @ curr->next */
curr->next = NEW;        // set curr (a) to point to NEW instead of b
```

Just remember to set `curr` before the nodes you need to work with in a singly-linked list.

Comment: @ProgrammingNerd Once you get into the swing of things, check out the problems. There are some good ones! Also, I made my example a bit more thorough.